# Im getting an "Unknown top level operator error" in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

So im trying to run a query that will group the documents by date. Along with having the Id i am trying to get a date, subtotal and count field return. The data is in an array in the collection called sales and the array's name is items and I then want to match for items.ProdID equals to "1".

Sample document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fdd03b5ba828047e400064d"),
        "salesno" : 161,
        "salesdate" : ISODate("2017-03-02T00:00:00Z"),
        "salestotal" : 1.95,
        "items" : [
                {
                        "ProdID" : "3514",
                        "ProdName" : "Processing Cap",
                        "AmtSold" : 3,
                        "UnitPrice" : 0.65
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fdd03b6ba828047e400064e"),
        "salesno" : 162,
        "salesdate" : ISODate("2017-03-02T00:00:00Z"),
        "salestotal" : 5.3,
        "items" : [
                {
                        "ProdID" : "24373",
                        "ProdName" : "Blue Water Cran + Cran/Lime  500ml",
                        "AmtSold" : 1,
                        "UnitPrice" : 2.35
                },
                {
                        "ProdID" : "18550",
                        "ProdName" : "CCC Mints Single",
                        "AmtSold" : 4,
                        "UnitPrice" : 0.25
                },
                {
                        "ProdID" : "12310",
                        "ProdName" : "Wibisco Shirley Large 105g",
                        "AmtSold" : 1,
                        "UnitPrice" : 1.95
                }
        ]
}
```

The query I ran :

```
db.Sales.aggregate([{$unwind : "$items"}, {$match : {"$items.ProdID" : "1"}}, {$group : {_id : "$salesdate", subTotal : {$sum : { $multiply  : [ "$items.AmtSold", "$items.UnitPrice" ] }}}}]);
```

The error Im getting

```
"ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $items.ProdID",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
} : aggregate failed :
```

I appreciate all the help I can get

Comment: remove $ from `items` in match stage `{$match : {"items.ProdID" : "1"}}`

Comment: @turivishal Funnily enough, I played around with it a bit more and I did that and now it works. Cheers ! Also do you know how I can transform this into something php can understand when it talks to my database?

Comment: i don't know about php syntax. you can ask new question and include php tag.